# Assign div html as attribute - Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div content (barcode) in my database as below and i want to assign it as attribute to my select option. When i assign it, the option gets distorted. How can i get this done ? I have attached an image of how it looks distorted.

When i take out the data-barcode attribute, it displays well

**JS**

```
$('#item').append('<option value="'+products.id+'"  data-barcode="'+products.barcode+'">'+products.name+'</option>');
```

[image]

**DIV**

```
<div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:114px;height:30px;">
<div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:12px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:30px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:38px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:44px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:56px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:66px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:74px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:84px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:88px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:98px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:106px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:110px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn’t there a `"` character in `products.barcode`? If so, you should escape it or convert it to base64 (encode: `window.btoa(products.barcode)`, decode: `window.atob($('#item > option[value="'+id+'"]').data('barcode'))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode and escape HTML tags

```js
$('#item').append('<option value="'+products.id+'"  data-barcode="'+encodeURIComponent(products.barcode)+'">'+products.name+'</option>');

// get data-barcode and decode
let barcode = decodeURIComponent($(el).attr('data-barcode'));
```

Answer (score 0):

How to encode with base64:

```js
products = {
  id: '12345',
  barcode: '<div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:114px;height:30px;"><div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:12px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:30px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:38px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:44px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:56px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:66px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:74px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:84px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:88px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:98px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:106px;top:0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:110px;top:0">&nbsp;</div></div>',
  name: 'phone'
}
$('#item').append('<option value="'+products.id+'"  data-barcode="'+window.btoa(products.barcode)+'">'+products.name+'</option>');
console.log(window.atob($('#item > option[value="'+products.id+'"]').data('barcode')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="item"></select>
```